# Can't get origin/request IP address in php from KVM apache website in bridge mode

Tags: ubuntu, php, iptables, kvm-virtualization, linuxmint

I have a apache webserver running on ubuntu 18.04 hosted on KVM
This KVM is running on Linux Mint 20.1 host OS

The networking is setup using bridge in KVM

```
<network connections="1">
  <name>host-bridge</name>
  <uuid>some-uuid</uuid>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0"/>
</network>
```

I have firewall rules to pass traffic from the real network to the bridge

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
#Pass to KVM Bridge
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o virbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

This is all working I am getting traffic to the host and routed to the kvm machine, external ips can connect and so can internal

Unfortunately I also have some custom html that changes behaviour through php based on whether the referrer is on the local lan or a remote ip

Since migrating to KVM from VmWare now everything comes up as sourced from the host ip address and this logic doesn't work

Is there a way to maintain the request ip address so i can keep the same behaviour?

I check ips in php with

```
function getUserIpAddress()
   {
    $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
      getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
      getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
      getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
      getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
      getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

      return $ip;
   }
```

And I've tried outputing all the above and they all show up as the host linux mint machines local lan IP

Comment: What are all the iptables rules for?

Comment: Without them the packets dont get to the KVM vm or out of it

Comment: That's odd. Did you block them somewhere else? You should not need any of those rules at all. And the masquerade rule is the one causing the problem.

Comment: I have a complex network setup including docker, multiple port forwarding and the default last rule is to drop anything not catered for in the previous rules
Looks like removing -j MASQUERADE but leaving everything else has worked can you post your response as an answer and I'll mark it correct with my notes :) ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing -j MASQUERADE resolved the issue

without having to open the box up to be unfirewalled

I have the last firewall rule as

```
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

So anything not previously handled is dropped as this is a production machine with multiple ports exposed to the internet

A brief snapshot of my current working rules is

```
    -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
     #Just one example rule
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -j DROP
    -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i br0 -o virbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This drops all packets I don't explicitly add keeping the VM relatively safe network wise and I can again get the external IP now in php correctly

Although I suspect this is still perhaps wrong and it may be routing all traffic through the bridge before hitting my main pc so I've inserted the docker container as a go between as the ports I have listed are generally all for my main pc and not the VM, regardless its working well enough for now

Thanks for your help